# Spring JPA - Oracle NUMBER to Long conversion issue

Tags: spring-data-jpa, oracle10g, java-17

JDK 17 - Spring 3.1.1 - Ojdbc8 -21.4.0.0

Using a Native Query to fetch data from Oracle. Column is of Type NUMBER.

Ex : 2048322424 Value of Column in Oracle.

Using a Long type in the Interface that maps the data from the query.

But the data in the Long type is 2048322432 -- the last 2 digits are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add TO_CHAR(column-name) to the NUMBER columns in the query to fix this issue.